# Java: Create unique List from an existing List keeping index numbers constant

Tags: java, arrays, list

I have two ArrayLists.

1. List of dates
2. List of respective data.

Both are **synchronized.** I sometimes have more than one data on a same date. I need to create two lists: unique dates and the data (averaged) respectively. So far, I have tried the following methods

```
int i = 1;
for(int it =0; it < predatetime.size() - 1; it++){
   //Compare each element with the next one
    if(predatetime.get(it+1) == predatetime.get(it)){
        i++;
        weight = preweight.get(it+1) + weight;
        //If equal, add weights and increment a divisor for averaging
    } 
    else {    //if not equal, add to the new lists
        if(it == predatetime.size() - 2){  //if the last element is not equal to its previous one, just add it to the list
            newDateTime.add(predatetime.get(it+1));
            newWeight.add(preweight.get(it+1));
            break;
        }
        weight = weight / i;
        newDateTime.add(predatetime.get(it));
        newWeight.add(weight);

        weight = preweight.get(it+1);    //re-initialize variables
        i = 1;
    }
    if(it == predatetime.size() - 2){
        weight = weight / i;
        newDateTime.add(predatetime.get(it));
        newWeight.add(weight);
    }
}
```

There are a lot of problems with this code.

If the list has only one element, it fails. (I know I can write 2 more lines to care of this). Is there a better way to do this?

I know there are similar questions on this website, but still I'm unable to resolve the problem.

Comment: Another way to do it would be to create a HashMap with the date as key and any composite data as value.For example :
HashMap<Date,List<Weight>>. 
Just initialize the map and on each iteration perform a get from this map.If not present add an entry on the map.If present get list and add another entry.

Comment: How do I calculate the average(mean) of data values if I do this?

Comment: In that case , keep the value as simple Object(not List) : with Attributes as SumOfWeights and Count .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the full solution

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
```

public class CustomList {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<String> date = new ArrayList<>();
    date.add("1");
    date.add("2");
    date.add("2");
    date.add("3");
    System.out.println(date);

    ArrayList<Integer> value = new ArrayList<>();
    value.add(1);
    value.add(2);
    value.add(4);
    value.add(3);
    System.out.println(value);

    new MyCls().createList(date, value);

}
```

}

class MyCls {

```
ArrayList uniqueDate = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList averageValue = new ArrayList<Integer>();
LinkedHashMap store = new LinkedHashMap<String, CountEntry>();

class CountEntry {
    int value;
    int count;

    CountEntry() {
    }

    CountEntry(int v, int c) {
        value = v;
        count = c;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }
}

public void createList(ArrayList<String> date, ArrayList<Integer> value) {
    for (int i = 0; i < date.size(); i++) {
        CountEntry tmp = (CountEntry) store.get(date.get(i));

        if (tmp == null) {
            store.put(date.get(i), new CountEntry(value.get(i), 1));
        } else {
            int tmpVal = tmp.getValue();
            int tmpCount = tmp.getCount();
            store.put(date.get(i), new CountEntry(value.get(i) + tmpVal, ++tmpCount));
        }
    }

    ArrayList<String> uniqueDate = new ArrayList<String>(store.keySet());
    ArrayList<CountEntry> tempAvgList = new ArrayList<CountEntry>(store.values());

    for (CountEntry ce : tempAvgList) {

        averageValue.add(ce.getValue() / ce.getCount());

    }
    System.out.println("Output");
    System.out.println(uniqueDate);
    System.out.println(averageValue);
}
```

}
/*

### OUTPUT Snap:

```
[1, 2, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 4, 3]
Output
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 3, 3]
```

*/

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfectly. But could you explain me what exactly this does?

Answer (score 0):

If you try to make your list elements unique why you not try to convert the list to set collection

`Set<Foo> foo = new HashSet<Foo>(myList);`

Comment: But how will I keep the respective data list synchronized? I mean, previous the data was with respect to the date list. If I do this, I lose tracks

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a Map instead with the dates as the key and have the value as a list. This will allow you to keep the dates unique, at the same allow you to have your data as a list.

```
Map<String, ArrayList<myData>> myMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<myData>>();
```

Then you can just find if your key exists, if it does add it to the array list by using the key to identify the correct list. If it doesnt exist it, add it to the map

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Rambler and @JulianGurung, I created a HashMap and it works

```
        HashMap<Integer, Float> hm = new HashMap<Integer,Float>();  
        int occurance = 0;
        float weight = 0;
        hm.put(predatetime.get(0), 0f); //initialize with the first value

        for(Map.Entry m : hm.entrySet()){  
            for( int it = 0; it < predatetime.size(); it++){
                if(m.getKey() == predatetime.get(it)){
                    weight = (Float) m.getValue() + preweight.get(it);  //Sum all the same data in order to avg later
                    hm.put(predatetime.get(it), weight);
                    occurance++;
                }
                else{   //if it is not equal, add the new element to the map
                    hm.put(predatetime.get(it), preweight.get(it));
                }
            }
            weight = weight / occurance;
            hm.put((Integer) m.getKey(), weight);
            weight = 0;
            occurance = 0;
        }
```

Comment: if it works, remember to accept the answer so it helps other people too

Comment: There's a problem in this. When I was comparing the HashMap's key with my datetime value, if it doesnt match, it will add the unequal values to the hashmap. But, during the next iteration, it doesnt take this new Hashmap's value into account. So, it just shows me the latest value from the list rather than giving me the average.